# python for loop slows down with iterations, it only loads and closes images

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have the following loop

```
from PIL import Image

for idx,img in enumerate(tqdm(all_images)):
    
    image = Image.open(img)
    image.close()
```

it starts with 400 iterations/s and then after some 500 iterations it slows down and eventually stabilizes at 20 iterations/s

Can anyone point me to why this happens ? or how to improve this ?

**Note** My loop has a more complex logic, but I stripped it down to this which is the bare minimum and which is causing this slowdown

Comment: Is your data all the same size in memory? That could slow it down.

Comment: more or less same size, so its not that the first few images were smaller

Comment: I did this loop (minus tqdm) and it treated 11800 picture in about 3 seconds. One stupid reason things can go to a crawl is if you add a `print` each loop as the console can be very slow when scrolling.